# Cannot resolve Object of type 'Nonetype' has no len

Tags: python, matplotlib, sqlite

I want to plot a graph between Platform and Build for those values that have Pass Value.Following is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import pylab
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('automate12.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE automate13(branch INTEGER,Platform VARCHAR(50),result VARCHAR(50),build                 INTEGER) """)
```

multiple_values = [(13,'Windows', 'Pass', 12),(14,'Solaris', 'Pass', 16),(15,'Mac', 'Pass', 20),  (16,'WindowsXP', 'Pass', 24),(17,'Windows Vista', 'Pass', 28),(18,'Linux', 'Fail', 32)]

```
conn.executemany("INSERT INTO automate13(branch,Platform,result,build)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",  multiple_values)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
curs = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT Platform,build FROM automate13 WHERE result='pass';"""
curs.execute(query)

def func():
      for row in curs:
          global Platform
          Platform.append(row['Platform'])
          return Platform

def func1():
     for row in curs:
          global Build
          Build.append(row['build'])
          return Build

pylab.figure(1)
x = range(10)
func()
pylab.xticks(x,func())
pylab.plot(x,func1(),"g")
pylab.show()
conn.close()
```

I'm getting the Error,'Object of Type 'NoneType' has no len().I can't resolve even though I've seen similar problems here.

Comment: Post the full traceback. It tells where the error is, among other things. Also, your `func()` and `func1()` functions will always return one row since you're returning inside the loop. Also, your `func` and `func1` are long-winded ways of saying `list(curs)`.

Comment: The traceback is:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Server\Apache2.2\htdocs\new_str_graph_sqlite.py", line 42, in <module>
    pylab.xticks(x,func())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1557, in xticks
    labels = ax.set_xticklabels(args[1], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2632, in set_xticklabels
    minor=minor, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1515, in set_ticklabels
    if i < len(ticklabels):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: I want to take Platform values from database on x-axes and build values on y-axes.The logic I'm trying is to fetch the values from the database and store it in a list.Then using matplotlib library functions plot them on the axes.Currently not getting any success...Kindly help me out..??